# jQuery - help with porting to a plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, porting

just wondering if anyone could have a look at my code that ive been trying to port to a plugin. There seem to be no errors getting logged, I just cant work out not working (this is my first attempt at a jQuery plugin so I really don't quite know what I'm doing, even though I've done a lot of work with the jQuery library).

Here is the original code (with comments):
http://jsfiddle.net/GZLQH/1/

And this is my attempt and a plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/PnEYN/

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: a piece of a note. you are using mootools on load. use jquery nowrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/aGFdJ/4/

The main point:

- Since the `this` pointer does not always point to the original element, you need to store a reference to it somewhere.

Side notes:

- As experimentX noted in the comments, you need to reference jQuery.
- `background:url(spark_01.png)` is not going to work in jsFiddle.
- Consider using a `for(var i = 0; i < sparks.length; i++)` when looping over a array, instead of the `for(var key in sparks)`.

Comment: Thank you dearly, I'll put those note above onto my list. Cheers.